# How would I get a list of posts from a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, query, post-type

I know the query method that you would use, that's not what I want. I could query the post type, then do the if statement with the while statement and go from there, but I am trying to populate a drop down with post titles. Thus I need an object.

What I have, which isn't working - there should be two posts in this object but their isnt, it comes back NULL, is:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'carousel', 'suppress_filters' => 0, 'numberposts' => -1, 'order' => 'ASC');
$content_block = get_post($args);

var_dump($content_block) // NULL
```

What would I do to get all the posts of the type `carousel`? which I know for a fact has 2 posts in it. I can go to `site.com/carousel/ctitle` to see `ctitle`'s content. But when I try the above I get `NULL`

Comment: `get_post` vs. `get_posts`, maybe?

Comment: Indeed, looks like a simple typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'carousel',
    'suppress_filters' => 0,
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$content_block = get_posts( $args );  // there was a typo in this line
var_dump($content_block); // it should work fine now
```

PS. I'm not sure why do you need "an object" and you can't do it with custom WP_Query. In the end, `get_posts` function builds custom WP_Query and returns result of it... ;)

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post.php#L1723